# Best way send a SAML assertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml

I'm using component space SAML 2.0 component and am trying to figure out how to send the assertion to a URL.  Whats the standard method of doing this?  Do I send it via HTTP POST?

Can someone show me some examples of the assertion being sent this way?  I'm open to suggestions, most of the examples show how the assertion is created, but I'm confused on how to send it.

Comment: What do you mean, "send an assertion"? One doesn't generally send an assertion except as part of a larger process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) creates an HTML FORM with the SAML assertion and POSTs it to the external application.  This seems to be a standard approach.  Just use JavaScript to automatically POST the form.